# Including a file multiple times (for templates)

Tags: php, templates

I am working on a simple template engine, and I was wondering if it's feasible to include the template file multiple times, once for each time the template is rendered. It basically goes like this:

```
function rendering_function_in_rendering_class()
{
    include $path_to_templates . get_class($this) . 'template.php';
}
```

And then in the template file:

```
<h1>Hello, <?php echo $this->awesomename ?>!</h1>
```

Comment: Include what exactly multiple times?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I mean the template file, not the template engine.

Comment: Well, did you try it? Did it work? What's the meaning of "feasible"? What's there to stop you doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function does exactly what you need:

```
<?php

function embed($file, $vars) {
  ob_start();
  extract($vars, EXTR_SKIP);
  include($file);
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  return $content;
}

?>
```

It takes file path as a first parameter and key/value array of variables which will be extract into the scope such that your template will be able to use them directly in HTML like this:

```
<h1><?php print $title; ?></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, functions in PHP may only be defined once. However, you can make more than one instance of each class:

```
$this1=new rendering();
$this2=new rendering();
echo $this1->awesomename;
echo $this2->awesomename;
```

Or use a function instide a class without the class being initialized:

```
$rendering::rendering_function_in_rendering_class();
```

Does that answer your question?